# How to interpret CVS version number?

Tags: version-control, cvs

I understood the simple part of cvs versioning, which is the first revision is 1.1, then an edit to 1.1 makes it 1.2 and so on, also that a branch would add a '.' to the revision number. so anything branching from 1.2 will then have numbers like 1.2.0.1 and so on.

What I don't understand is how the first number changes? how do I go from 1.1 to 2.1?

Answer (score 0):

On searching further, I got this from http://www-e815.fnal.gov/webspace/cvs/commands.html#commit

New major release number When you make a major release of your product, you might want the revision numbers to track your major release number. You should normally not care about the revision numbers, but this is a thing that many people want to do, and it can be done without doing any harm. To bring all your files up to the RCS revision 3.0 (including those that haven't changed), you might do:

$ cvs commit -r 3.0

which changes the first digit to 3. It has been mentioned that this is not advised, and I guess its there just because it was there as a part of RCS.